# Access HTML element value inside NgClass

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ng-class

so i would like to retrieve the value of an html input inside it's ngClass to compare it later in a pipe .
Exemple :

```
<input type="email" ... [ngClass]="myPipe(input.value)" >
```

Or maybe like this :

```
 <input type="email" ... [ngClass]="item.value | myPipe" >
```

Do you know any way of achieving this ?

Thanks .

Comment: `<input type="email" #myInput [ngClass]="myPipe( myInput.value )" >` maybe?

Comment: Thank you @JeremyThille it's now working good and as expected !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from my comment above :

```
<input type="email" #myInput [ngClass]="myPipe( myInput.value )" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="email" [ngModel]="input.value" [ngClass]="myPipe(input.value)" >
```

Comment: I think it will say `input is undefined`

Comment: I guess he defined input in the controller

Comment: OP wants `input` to be this specific `<input>` element. The way to do this is to give it a name by adding `#myInput`, then its value is directly accessible through `#myInput.value`.

Comment: if he defines input.value on his controller, when the input value change the "input.value" will be updated